# CSS and other resource files are not getting mapped in Spring MVC project

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created a page with an external CSS file. I am unable to mapp my css file with my jsp page.The same code is working fine in netbeans but causing issue in Sprint Tool Suite(eclipse).

[image: Project Structure]

web.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>sk</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springfamework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sk</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">




    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sk"></context:component-scan>


</beans>
```

JSP page

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact and Feedback</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" media="all" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO" height="112" width="118"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="about.html">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="images.html">Images</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="downlaods.html">Downloads</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="news.html">News</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="selected">
                            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contents">
                <div class="box">
                    <div>
                        <div id="contact" class="body">
                            <h1>Contact</h1>
                            <form action="addfeedback" method="post">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Name:</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" value="" name="name" class="txtfield"></td>
                                        </tr> <tr>
                                            <td>Email:</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" value="" name="mail" class="txtfield"></td>
                                        </tr> <tr>
                                            <td>Subject:</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" value="" name="sub" class="txtfield"></td>
                                        </tr> <tr>
                                            <td class="txtarea">Message:</td>
                                            <td><textarea name="msg"></textarea></td>
                                        </tr> <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td><input type="submit" value="" class="btn"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                            <h2>Spring MVC Test Page</h2>
                            <p>
                                <span>Address:</span> Integral University Boys Hostel
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <span>Contact Number:</span> +91-9479711997
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <span>E-Mail ID</span> shahbaz275817@yahoo.com
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div>
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rooms.html">Videos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="dives.html">Images</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="foods.html">Downloads</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="news.html">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="connect">
                    <a href="http://pinterest.com/fwtemplates/" target="_blank" class="pinterest"></a> <a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/facebook/" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a> <a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/twitter/" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a> <a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/googleplus/" target="_blank" class="googleplus"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
                © 2017 by SHAHBAZ KHAN. All Rights Reserved
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You use <default-servlet-handler />  and search this tag.

Comment: tried but still not working in eclipse...working fine in netbeans

Comment: Create new project and check init configuration.